# How to calculate median with groupby considering specific rows only

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
                   'B': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'C': [np.nan, 1, 3, 5, 6, 2, np.nan, np.nan]})
   A  B    C
0  1  1  NaN
1  2  1  1.0
2  3  1  3.0
3  4  1  5.0
4  1  2  6.0
5  2  2  2.0
6  3  2  NaN
7  4  2  NaN
```

Along with it goes the following map:

```
df_map = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                       'N': [2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1]})
   A  N
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  2  1
3  2  4
4  3  2
5  3  1
6  4  3
7  4  1
```

What I would like to do is fill the `NaN` values with `mean` of each group defined by `B` but only consider rows whose `A` corresponds to `N` in `df_map`.

For example:

`NaN` at index `0` will be filled with mean of `[1.0, 3.0]` because `1` points to `[2, 3]`.

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
   A  B    C
0  1  1  2.0 # mean of 1.0 and 3.0
1  2  1  1.0
2  3  1  3.0
3  4  1  5.0
4  1  2  6.0
5  2  2  2.0
6  3  2  4.0 # mean of 6.0 and 2.0
7  4  2  6.0 # mean of 6.0 and NaN
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i dint understand how did you get 2 in first row could tou plz explain more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully someone can fix to make a bit more elegant, but this should get what you want, using a combination of multiple `merge`'s and `map`:

```
fill_map = (df.merge(df_map, on='A')
            .merge(df, left_on=['B', 'N'], right_on=['B', 'A'], suffixes=('', '_'))
            .groupby(['B', 'A'])['C_'].mean())


df['C'] = df['C'].fillna(df[['B', 'A']].apply(tuple, axis=1).map(fill_map))
```

[out]

```
   A  B    C
0  1  1  2.0
1  2  1  1.0
2  3  1  3.0
3  4  1  5.0
4  1  2  6.0
5  2  2  2.0
6  3  2  4.0
7  4  2  6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve it by applying a function like this:

```
def func(x):
    return np.nanmean( df[ df['A'].isin( df_map[df_map.A==x['A']].N.values) & (df.B==x.B)].C)

df.loc[df.C.isna(), 'C'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B    C
0  1  1  2.0
1  2  1  1.0
2  3  1  3.0
3  4  1  5.0
4  1  2  6.0
5  2  2  2.0
6  3  2  4.0
7  4  2  6.0
```